# XAML control to inherit from templates

Tags: silverlight, xaml

What controls are there to inherit from that has the property of Children and supports templating when building a custom usercontrol.

Currently I know about **Panel**, but it does not support properties and methods like **DefaultStyleKey** and **GetTemplateChild()**;

Is there an interface that I can inherit from for templates such as:

```
public class Scroller : Panel, ITemplates //Something like ITemplates
{
   public override void OnApplyTemplate()
   {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        container = GetTemplateChild("container") as StackPanel; //I want to be able to do this

        this.Children; //And also be able to use this
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ItemsControl. It has an Items property and its template is very flexible as demonstrated by the fact that TabControl, ListBox, ComboBox, etc all derive from it.

Comment: For some reason, thats what was there before but it would not work. I going to be using my custom control inside an ItemsPanelTemplate for a listbox. When I inherit from ItemsControl, it tells me that I need a root of Panel.

Comment: Correct, if you are trying to override layout of a ListBox then you have to create a Panel and you don't get a template. A panel has no visual representation, it simply lays out its children and thus there is no need for a template.

Comment: You should instead decide if you want to create a custom ItemsControl (in other words, no ListBox) or if you just want to override the layout of a ListBox.

Comment: I think I'll use it as a custom ItemsControl. Like how ListBox items are called ListItems, what do I call the items for this control? I'll be attaching a Generated Items Template to it and bind it to an ItemSource.